# Issue in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, wpfdatagrid

```
DataClasses1DataContext MyCountry = new DataClasses1DataContext("Data source=.; 
User ID=sa; Password=; Integrated security=true; Initial catalog=training;");
var _MyCountry = from cntry in MyCountry.GetTable<country>() select cntry;
grd_table.DataSource = _MyCountry;
```

when I try to bind the countries in `grd_table`. It shows the error:

```
System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'DataSource' 
and no extension method 'DataSource' accepting a first argument of 
type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be 
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**.
```

what should I do to solve this error.

Comment: Did you really not even care to look up the properties of a datagrid in the MSDN / docs?

Answer (score 0):

Surely that's a compile time error; so I assume it's throwing the error when you're building your project.

It doesn't have a `DataSource` property, use `ItemsSource` instead

Answer (score 0):

You are not ought to directly connect your datatable to the DataGrid via a DataSource-Property like in WinForms. Use DataBinding! :)

You can set the Databinding in XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" />
```

or in C# in the Code-Behind - even if I prefer the XAML-Way.

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Customer.GetSampleCustomerList();
```

You should really read for [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) in WPF as these techniques will give you much help in future developments. It's way easier than I thought in the beginning - and fast after you learned the first steps.

There are good tutorials for datagrid-databinding out there one in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.itemssource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and a [Blog](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) I once found.